# Check if convex polygon is completely contained completely within another convex polygon.

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, polygons

How can I determine if a convex polygon is completely contained within another convex polygon where speed is critical? I've thought about doing this, which will only use inequalities:

*pcp = potentially contained polygon*

1. Iterate through every one of pcp's points, comparing each one to every one of the containing polygon's points.
2. Determine if pcp's point is to the left/right and to the bot/top of the first point.
3. Check against every other point of the containing polygon. If the pcp's point is not the same orientation horizontally and vertically as the first check in step 2, then the pcp's point is not contained, thus the entire pcp isn't contained.

Am I on the right track? I haven't implemented this so I have no idea if it'll work. Are there faster methods or improvements that could be made?

Answer (score 1):

A convex polygon can be given either by its vretices or, often more adequate, by inequalities $a_ix+b_iy\ge c_i$ describing the half planes whose intersection is the polygon.
With the latter form, a  point of the plane is inside the polygon iff all iniequalities hold for its coordinates (or possibly on the boundary if we have equality in at least one of the inequalities).
Thus if we have the *vertices* for the potentially contained polygon and the *inequalities* for the potentially containing polygon, you need only check each of the vertices against each of the iniequalities. This takes $O(nm)$ time if $n,m$ are the number of vertices. (Note that we made no use of the fact that the potentially contained polygon is convex)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your explanation was a bit too sophisticated for me. What do aix, biy, and ci represent? Also, how does the half plane relate to the containment check?

Comment: @JPtheK9 A convex polygon is the intersection of finitely many half planes. A point is inside the polygon iff it is inside all these half planes.

Comment: Oh, I see. If that's the case, should I do Dot (*pcp*[i], (*cp*[i] - *cp*[i-1]).Right) >= 0 to find if the point is under the half-plane, where *cp = Containing Polygon*? I guess if the verticies were going counter-clockwise, I'd have to change the inequality to <= but that's just a matter of inequalities.